# jQuery dialog is not opening

Tags: jquery, html

I do not know why but my Jquery dialog is not appearing.

html code

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Uploaded Image">
     <p> sample jquery dialog  box </p>
 </div>
```

Script Code

```
                <script>
                $(function(){
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        model:true,
                        show: {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 1000
                        },
                        hide: {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 1000
                        }
                        buttons:{
                            "Uploads": function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                            "Cancel" : function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        } 
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

I am using chrome

Comment: I think 'model' should be 'modal'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script was missing some `,` and `}`

```
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        }, //Missing ,
        buttons:{
        "Uploads": function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }, //Missing ,
        "Cancel" : function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRtHkeS3i6X1r7gJFqUT?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing comma separator `","` after `hide` and inside the `button`

Try this

```
$(function(){
     $("#dialog").dialog({
      modal:true,
      show: {
              effect: "blind",
              duration: 1000
            },
      hide: {
              effect: "blind",
              duration: 1000
             },
      buttons:{
               "Uploads": function(){
                             $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                "Cancel" : function(){
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        } 
                    });
                });
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/awVEN/1/)